# Ubuntu20.04 fresh install, no software store

Tags: 20.04, software-center

Software Center only shows "Editors Pick" and categories nothing else when "All" is selected. Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: Hey SocietySpy! Your question doesn't seem clear to me. Can you please be more detailed? There's no app named "*Software Center*" in Ubuntu 20.04.  Please check the app name.

Comment: I'm having the same experience with the Ubuntu Software (gnome-software) application. I cannot see any of my installed programs. It was called the software center in previous versions of Ubuntu. I do not think this question is unclear for this reason. I suppose this is more of a question than an answer, since I have the same question.